# Gitolite through password instead of a key

Tags: git, gitolite

Is there a way to make GitoLite work through passwords rather than through public+private keys? For example, to make it in such way that the user can clone the repository only through his/her own gitolite password confirming his/her identity, not by generating a key pair for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The entire point of gitolite is that it uses keypairs to determine someone's identity, so that it can manage users, instead of having to manage them on the system.

You could *bypass* gitolite by giving some users shell access to the repository directories, and having them push directly via ssh (and authenticate with their method of choice, e.g. passwords) but this really would be bypassing it. Gitolite would no longer be able to do all of the fancy things it does, namely checking to see if a given user is authorized to perform a given operation.

Comment: Certainly username/password authentication is not possible with the usual SSH-based authentication used with gitolite, but the (alternative) [http mode](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/http.html) of modern gitolite can use whatever forms of authentication the web server supports (and most web servers probably do support a varienty of username/password authentication methods).

Answer (score 1):

Password authentication is possible with *gitolite*. 
Let's say user X is authenticated using password. 
The workaround is that you need to create a custom script that acts like a shell for user X.
The script redirects the git commands to the gitolite's user using key authentication.
The next step is to make generate a key pair for user X account and add the public key to the gitolite admin's key.

[Here](http://colonelpanic.net/2011/03/enabling-git-access-via-password-authentication-with-gitolite/) is a link that explains it all.