# How to setup a Git server which use User/Password?

Tags: git, gitolite

I need to build a Git server which allows clients from both Window and *nix to read and write.
There are many tutorials out there showing how to build gitolite server over ssh, which required clients to send its public keys. But it's annoying to generate keys and reconfig gitolite everytime i want to pull/push my source to/from someone's computer.

Are there anyway to build a git server simply using user/password?

Thanks
Jack

Comment: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite Try this one? Not sure whether it uses User/Password. :p

Comment: You might consider using webserver with WebDav module to support Git via HTTPS, eg.: http://www.xiaoka.com/blog/2008/04/13/git-repository-over-http-webdav-with-nginx/

Comment: @MarcinGil: The WebDAV-based method is practically obsolete. Git 1.6.6 introduced a CGI-based [“smart HTTP” transport](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html). Also, modern [gitolite supports “smart HTTP”](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/http.html), too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gitolite through password instead of a key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434997/gitolite-through-password-instead-of-a-key)

Comment: thank you guys, gitolite's Smart HTTP is probably right way to go.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, since that other question specifies use of Gitolite, but that does seem to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Standard git doesn't require you to use a key pair. 
If you don't have a public key available, it will just prompt your password when doing an interaction with the server.

The requirement is however that everyone contributing has a *nix account on the server. Setting up an anonymous, read only access to the repo is easy with [git-daemon](http://man.he.net/man1/git-daemon).

That said, I think you misunderstood the key stuff. You only need to configure stuff and generate keys *once* for every new user, not every time you access the repo.

Comment: Just need to remember to carry your keys with you if you switch workstations often.